# ¿Porqué no me modifica el registro mediante PHP?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

tengo un problema a la hora de hacer UPDATE mediante PHP.
El código es el siguiente:

```
//Recojo los datos
$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$id = $_POST["id"];
$h1 = $_POST["hora1"];
$h2 = $_POST["hora2"];

$link = Conectarse();
echo "UPDATE horasextra SET HORAS1='".$h1."' AND HORAS2='".$h2."' WHERE COD_EMPLE='".$id."' AND FECHA='".$fecha."'";
mysql_query("UPDATE horasextra SET HORAS1='".$h1."' AND HORAS2='".$h2."' WHERE COD_EMPLE='".$id."' AND FECHA='".$fecha."'", $link);
$affected = mysql_affected_rows();
mysql_query("COMMIT");
echo $affected;
?>
```

Lo que me muestra el echo de la sentencia es:
`UPDATE horasextra SET HORAS1='2' AND HORAS2='3' WHERE COD_EMPLE='43122' AND FECHA='2018-04-03'`

Vamos, la sentencia al parecer es correcta, pero en cambio al hacer `mysql_affected_rows()` me devuelve 0.

He realizado una consulta desde el mismo phpMyAdmin para que comprueben que existe dicho registro pero las horas1 y horas2 no han sido afectadas:
[image: Registro]

Espero me ayuden a resolver que ocurre, gracias.

Comment: Prueba a copiar esa sentencia del echo y pegarla directamente en el PhpMyAdmin para ver si tiene efecto

Answer (score 1):

Vale, ya está solucionado, el problema estaba en que no debo poner AND para actualizar varias columnas, sino utilizar la coma:

Mal:`UPDATE horasextra SET HORAS1='".$h1."' AND HORAS2='".$h2."' WHERE COD_EMPLE='".$id."' AND FECHA='".$fecha."'"`

Bien:`UPDATE horasextra SET HORAS1='".$h1."', HORAS2='".$h2."' WHERE COD_EMPLE='".$id."' AND FECHA='".$fecha."'"`

Vamos, típico fallo de sintaxis que no lo ves durante un rato.

Gracias de todos modos.